# How to grant privileges to root in mysql through SSH

Tags: mysql, ssh

I am trying to [install the Clouse](http://www.oblaksoft.com/documentation/getting-started-with-clouse/) script on our server and I am connecting via SSH.

Everytime I get to the install part in SSH I am getting this error:

```
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1: INSERT command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'plugin'
```

I tried connecting to mySQL by typing my in the command line, once I am connected I try running this (for demo purposes this is false info - skittles would be my database, password1234 would be the password):

```
GRANT ALL ON skittles.* TO root@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password1234';
```

It tells me success that 0 rows were effected in 0 seconds and then I use `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`

then quit and try to install again and keep getting the same error.  Is there something I am doing wrong in the command line with the GRANT ALL ?  Not sure why it is not working, not familiar with SSH to much so I would appreciate any insight

Comment: This sounds like it's about granting privileges to `root` in MySQL, not privileges in SSH. So the title is misleading. The fact that you are logged into SSH isn't relevant other than `mysql` defaults to the logged in user, but that's changeable by command line parameters. You need admin privileges in `mysql` to start with to do the `GRANT ALL...`.

Comment: Changed the title, hopefully that clears up any confusion - thanks

Comment: You'll get more of the right viewers to your question that way. :)

Comment: MySQL stores database privileges in the mysql.db table. Please check whether Privileges are updated in mysql.db or not?